# Map JSON to existing deep object structure

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, mobx

Say I have the following Typescript model:

```
class Person{
     public Address: Address;
     public FirstName: string;
     public LastName: string;
     constructor(){
         this.Address = new Address();
     }
}
```

And I get an exact representation of this object from a server via JSON.

How would I go about generically setting the properties of both the Person and the Address but **leave the existing objects intact**.

So similar to this, but generically:

```
public SetData(json:any){
   this.Address.City = json.Address.City;
   this.Address.Province = json.Address.Province;
   this.FirstName = json.FirstName;
}
```

The gotcha being that the original objects must remain and have there setters called as they are Mobx observables. This rules out Object.assign and any 'extend' methods I have found.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [**extendObservable**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html)? `extendObservable(this, json)` in `SetData` might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final implementation based of Amids:

import * as _ from "underscore";

```
export class ObjectMapper
{
    public static MapObject(source: any, destination: any) {
       _.mapObject(source, (val, key) => {
        if(_.isObject(val))
        {
            this.MapObject(val, destination[key]);
        }
        else if(_.isArray(val))
        {
            const array = destination[key];
            for(var i in val)
            {
                const newObject = {};
                _.extend(newObject, val[i]);
                array.push(newObject);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            destination[key] = val;
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In somewhat simplified case you can do it manually without too much [effort](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Address%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20public%20City%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20public%20Province%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Person%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20public%20Address%3A%20Address%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20public%20FirstName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20public%20LastName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Address%20%3D%20new%20Address()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20private%20SetDataInternal(target%3A%20any%2C%20json%3A%20any)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20json%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22undefined%22%20%7C%7C%20json%20%3D%3D%3D%20null)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20propName%20of%20Object.keys(json))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20val%20%3D%20target%5BpropName%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20val%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22object%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.SetDataInternal(val%2C%20json%5BpropName%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%5BpropName%5D%20%3D%20json%5BpropName%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20public%20SetData(json%3A%20any)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.SetDataInternal(this%2C%20json)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20json%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Address%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20City%3A%20%22AAA%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Province%3A%20%22BBB%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20FirstName%3A%20%22CCC%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20p%20%3D%20new%20Person()%3B%0D%0Ap.SetData(json)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(p)%3B):

```
class Address
{
  public City: string;
  public Province: string;
}

class Person{
     public Address: Address;
     public FirstName: string;
     public LastName: string;

     constructor() {
         this.Address = new Address();
     }

     private SetDataInternal(target: any, json: any)
     {
       if (typeof json === "undefined" || json === null)
       {
         return;
       }

       for (let propName of Object.keys(json))
       {
         const val = target[propName];

         if (typeof val === "object")
         {
           this.SetDataInternal(val, json[propName]);
         }
         else
         {
           target[propName] = json[propName];
         }
       }
     }

     public SetData(json: any)
     {
       this.SetDataInternal(this, json);
     }
}

const json = {
  Address: {
    City: "AAA",
    Province: "BBB"
  },
  FirstName: "CCC"
}

const p = new Person();
p.SetData(json);

console.log(p);
```

It surely miss some checks and corner cases validations, but apart from that it does what you ask for.

Comment: This led me down the right path :) I'll post my final solution below. Thanks.